# JQuery Textarea val - created dynamic

Tags: jquery

i am creating a textarea like this:

```
var visit_detailSpan = $("<span class='visit'>Visits: (optional)</span>");             
var visit = $("<textarea rows='4' cols='40' class='visit' id='visit'></textarea>");
```

now, i am  trying to get the value of the above textarea: when the user click on submit button: but i am getting `undefined`

```
var submitVisit = function(){  

            $.getJSON(
                options.ServiceUrl,
                {                    
                   ......,
                   ......,
                   visit: $('#visit').val()   //<<<<<<
                },
               function (response) { ... }                      

             );

        }
```

Comment: lol, silly people overthink stuff. You already gave it an asignment, so just use that. `visit.val()`

Comment: i am getting `undefined` when i do `$('#visit').val()`

Comment: Where do you add those elements to the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

if visit =

```
var visit = $("<textarea rows='4' cols='40' class='visit' id='visit'></textarea>")
```

or even if it was

```
var visit = $("<textarea />").attr({ id: 'visit', rows: 4, cols: 40 }).addClass("visit")
```

Either way, you already established the variable `visit` to be the jQuery Object of the HTML Textarea Element, so to get the value on recall is as easy as

```
visit.val();
```

Whenever you asign a an element as a jquery object to a variable, you don't need to recall that elements id, and if you do recall it by id and get undefined, then you ddn't actually post your dynamic html to the dom yet or the id was not established correctly.

If after you establish your variable, a quick look at `console.log(visit)` should yeild something like the following in your console:

```
[<textarea id=​"visit" rows=​"4" cols="40" class="visit" >​</textarea>​]
```

As you can see, `visit` is your element, so again, i reiterate, no need at this point to call on that element by id.